# Get an infinite loop using method_added and initialize together

Tags: ruby

I want to hook some actions in all methods in the object, but my attempt is seems to be getting in an infinite loop.

Once I comment out the `initialize` the problem is fixed.

How can I fix this?

I call the object `TaskRecord.new` in this way, and then raise the message like `stack overflow`

```
class TaskRecord
  @@cnt = 0
  #To add log when calls a method
  def self.method_added(name)    
    if /hook/.match(name.to_s) or method_defined?("#{name}_without_hook")
      return 
    end
    class_eval do 
      alias_method "#{name}_without_hook" , "#{name}"
      define_method name do
        p "#{name} called"
        send "#{name}_without_hook"
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize
    ...
  end

  def somemethods
    ...
  end
```

Comment: can you show how you were calling the method which lead to *infinite loop* ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit HI I UPDATED IT

Answer (score 1):

Because `initialize` is a private method, try this:

```
class Test
   def initialize
   end
   alias_method :old_initialize, :intialize
end

Test.method_defined? 'initialize'     # returns false
Test.method_defined? 'old_initialize' # returns false too
```

You can fix your code with `private_method_defined?`

```
if /hook/.match(name.to_s) or
  method_defined?("#{name}_without_hook") or
  private_method_defined?("#{name}_without_hook")
```